# volatile boolean

Tags: java, synchronization, volatile

If I have a volatile boolean (let's call it valid), is the following piece of code thread-safe in Java?

```
if (valid)
  return;
valid = true;
```

Or, do I need to synchronize since valid is set to true only if it's false (hence set of valid depends on its current value)?

Comment: Volatile does *not* solve _race conditions_. Volatile solves the problem that value stored in "valid" is shared to all other threads _with access to valid_. So if "valid" is not static and there's no static reference to the object containing "valid", then no other thread will know about "valid".

Answer (score 8):

This needs to be synchronized, because if one thread evaluates valid as false, and then suspends execution before the assignment, then another one comes along and also checks valid as false, before setting valid to true, you will have two threads running code following on from here (which presumably you don't want).

Comment: This is only true if there are actually two threads executing the same code (or doing write operations, anyway)

Comment: If your code assumes that there is only one thread that can run it at one time, then it is not 'thread-safe'.  Same problem if you assume that the value cannot be written to by other threads in a small part of the code which has access to this variable, has to hold for the whole module!

Comment: To be more explicit, if ALL threads are only doing read operations, everything is fine; if just one of them has the ability to write over the value, synchronization is required on all code that uses it where consistency problems would occur.

Answer (score 5):

Use AtomicBoolean.  Instances can be simultaneously checked and set.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion... but it kind of first requires that you realize you need synchronization :-).

Answer (score 4):

It isn't thread-safe. But if this is the whole code, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** An all-around superior alternative would be [`AtomicBoolean`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), which uses low-level operations to achieve conditional updates without synchronization.

There are two separate (i.e. non-atomic) accesses to the flag, thus synchronization is necessary *unless* this thread is the only one doing write operations on the flag. Even then it would probably be good to have synchronization just to be sure in case of future changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not threadsafe, but it really depends on your other code whether or not it is safe to do that.

Do you require that the code following `valid = true` only be executed once by a single thread? If so, then your code is not safe because any number of threads can read a `false` value of `valid`, and then end up setting it to `true`. For example:

```
if (valid)
  return;
// Imagine every single one of your threads stops and blocks here.
// They will all wake up again and set valid to true and then
// execute the code to follow.
valid = true;
```

But if you just want to guarantee that the code after `valid = true` is executed at most one time by *any* thread... then what you have is fine. But if that's the behavior you require I would achieve that by other means, because using `volatile` in that case will just look like you don't know what you're doing. For example, you could just not share the `valid` variable across threads, and allow each thread to just execute the code once.

Also, when in doubt while reasoning about synchronization and volatile... just use synchronization. It is usually more clear, and will get you everything you wanted from using `volatile`, except it will be easier to reason how the code works.

Answer (score 1):

thread-safety is a system wide property. you cannot look at a piece of code in isolation and call it thread safe/unsafe. it depends on how other threads interact with it and what is the consistency requirement. that being said, most thread-safe design has while() loop instead of if() block, so, your design is most likely incorrect:)

Comment: Thread safety by using atomic or synchronized operations, not by using while loops. And you are right that thread safety is a system property, but this code is inherently not suitable for multithreading if valid is a shared variable.

Comment: I'm not saying using while loops make it thread safe. I say thread safe code usually have while loops, and if-block typically indicate mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

According to great paper by Brian Goetz 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/ 
"You can use volatile variables instead of locks only under a restricted set of circumstances. Both of the following criteria must be met for volatile variables to provide the desired thread-safety:

- Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value.
- The variable does not participate in invariants with other variables.

Basically, these conditions state that the set of valid values that can be written to a volatile variable is independent of any other program state, including the variable's current state."
So it must be synchronized with a lock. It is not thread-safe as is.